# bag_to_pcd failed to contact master

Tags: ros, rosbag, bag-to-pcd, ros-pcl, pcd

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm trying to run 'bag_to_pcd' from the terminal but keep getting the following error..

```
[ERROR] [1320830633.224372085]: [registerPublisher] Failed to contact master at [localhost:11311].  Retrying... 

rosrun pcl_ros bag_to-pcd points2.bag /camera/depth/points2 mr
```

where,

- points2.bag is my bag file
- /camera/depth/points2 is the topic
- mr is the directory where to put the pcd files

if i ctrl c out of it, the following comes up...

```
^Cterminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::TimeNotInitializedException' 
  what():  Cannot use ros::Time::now() before the first NodeHandle has been created or ros::start() has been called.  If this is a standalone app or test that just uses ros::Time and does not communicate over ROS, you may also call ros::Time::init() 
Aborted
```

and rosbag info points2.bag gives me...

```
path:        points2.bag 
version:     2.0 
duration:    8.6s 
start:       Nov 08 2011 15:23:14.96 (1320762194.96) 
end:         Nov 08 2011 15:23:23.58 (1320762203.58) 
size:        156.9 MB 
messages:    428 
compression: none [143/143 chunks] 
types:       sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 [1158d486dd51d683ce2f1be655c3c181] 
topics:      /camera/depth/points2   428 msgs    : sensor_msgs/PointCloud2
```

thanks for reading!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11862/bag_to_pcd-failed-to-contact-master/) by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2011-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should start `roscore` before running `bag_to_pcd`.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-10**:
If you can't figure that out yourself, please post a *new* question.

**Comment by [liquidmonkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/1325/liquidmonkey/) on 2011-11-09**:
yep, that was it. but now there seems to be an issue with the way bag-to_pcd is doing the actual conversion. i get  a bunch of binary pcd files which only display a few points when using rxbag.